# Closing parent form when child form also closes

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

Aside from my main form I have another form, frmAddFixture, which can open frmAddReport.

I'm simply trying to close frmAddFixture when "No" is selected from the msgbox, which also closes (successfully) Me (frmAddReport). If "Yes" is selected frmAddFixture should stay open, which it does. But I can't get it to close for "No". I've tried adding my own handler in to detect when frmAddReport is closing, but I couldn't get that working.

frmAddReport Code (run after a "Submit" button has been clicked):

```
Private Sub showMsg()

Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to add another player report for this fixture?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Add further reports")

    Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                    isNewFixture = False
    Me.Close()

    Case MsgBoxResult.No
                    isNewFixture = True
                    Me.Close()
                    ''Close frmAddFixture
                    'frmAddFixture.Dispose()
                    'frmAddFixture.Close()
                    'frmAddFixture.Hide()
        End Select
End Sub
```

Attempted:

```
    Private Sub frmAddReport_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        frmAddFixture.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's too "messy" for me to understand you clearly.

Comment: Apologies, I simply want to be able to close/dispose of frmAddFixture once its child form, frmAddReport, has been closed.

Comment: Just subscribe its FormClosed event and close yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean @HansPassant- please could you explain in code?

Comment: Is there any progress in this question? Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you are trying to do.

Let's ignore the message box for a moment and say that we have two forms : `Form1` and `Form2`. We want that as soon as `Form2` is colsed, `Form1` will be disposed (closed) as well. I'ts pretty simeple :

```
Public Class Form2

' Occurs when Form2 is closed (note the event handler).
Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    Form1.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this suggestion- the event triggered but form1 did not close.

Comment: Wired... I tried it yesterday and it worked perfectly. Have you tried putting a breakpoint and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, the event triggers but the form is not disposed- I've edited the question to show what I put in.